# Android Camera2 configure crashes without reporting proper error

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying some preview frame processing on top of camera2basic example from android. createCaptureSession call is failing with no so useful error reporting. Can someone help me understand whats going wrong?

Following works and still image capturing works as expected

```
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
```

Following also works with my custom frame processing happening

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mFrameReader.getSurface());
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mFrameReader.getSurface()), ....
```

However, its fails without proper error reporting when try both the things together

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mFrameReader.getSurface());
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface(), mFrameReader.getSurface()),
```

I see following error in logs and my app crashes

> 06-20 06:37:56.430 28839-29176/com.example.android.camera2basic
>   E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session;
>   configuration failed

For reference heres the whole method

```
    /**
 * Creates a new {@link CameraCaptureSession} for camera preview.
 */
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;

        // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

        // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mFrameReader.getSurface());

        // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface(), mFrameReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {
                            // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);

                            // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                    }
                }, null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have any conclusion yet? I'm trying to do something very similar (like doing preview, frame processing, and still image capturing in one session) and got the same error... this would even reboot one of my Samsung devices. btw. Using old Camera API is working fine.

Comment: And according to Android documentation, the failure `...can happen if the set of requested outputs contains unsupported sizes, or too many outputs are requested at once`. Not sure if 3 outputs are "too many".

Comment: @WeiWANG is correct. I got the same error when trying to two outputs with large resolutions ie 4290x2800. I lowered the resolution for both outputs and it worked fine. My guess is that camera hardware just cannot handle multiple hi-res outputs.